# Different types of scanf usage in C

Tags: c, scanf

I know in order to use scanf to get input strings having spaces we use a call such as:

```
scanf("%[^\n]",str);
```

which will match all the characters up to new line. But I found another call of scanf:

```
scanf("%[ A-Za-z]",str);
```

For me both are working fine!But I am not able to figure out what is the difference between the two!?

Which method is should I use while dealing with string with spaces?

Comment: Which of the two scans a %$#*! character?

Comment: http://c-faq.com/stdio/scanfprobs.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> what is the difference between the two!?

The first one scans everything up to a newline character, the second one scans letters and space only.

> Which method is should i use while dealing with string with spaces?

Neither one, have a look at [`fgets()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/fgets.html) instead:

```
char buf[LINE_MAX];
fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), stdin);
```

Comment: Indeed [fgets](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fgets/) possibly in combination with [sscanf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/sscanf/)

Comment: And `scanf` may have a buffer overflow problem

Comment: @YuHao Indeed. That's **exactly** one of the reasons why I suggested the use of `fgets()`.

Answer (score 0):

Its better if you use the first one which omits newline and accepts every character besides it. That means you can supply a complete line and scanf will end read in when you press enter. Its similar to `gets()` function which can be included from string.h

Comment: `gets` is prototyped in `stdio.h`. In general it's better to use `fgets` & `sscanf` over `gets` and `scanf` - http://c-faq.com/stdio/scanfprobs.html

Comment: `gets()` is removed from the latest version of C (2011).  Using alternatives is a better route.